# Populating Cocoon + Autocomplete - error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, autocomplete, cocoon-gem

I'm using these gems and I want to populate a form based on the name of the ingredient. Everything is working. However, when I try to Create the Recipe I get the following error: 
**Couldn't find Ingredient with ID=1 for MealIngredient with ID=**

---

**VIEWS:**
This is the **_form** partial required by Cocoon

```
<div class = "row">
  <div class= "col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <%= simple_form_for(@meal) do |f| %>
      <%= f.error_notification %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <%= f.input :name %>
      </div>
      <h3>ingredientes</h3>
      <fieldset id="ingredients">
        <ol>
          <%= f.fields_for :meal_ingredients do |meal_ingredient| %>
            <%= render "meal_ingredient_fields", :f => meal_ingredient  %>
          <% end %>
        </ol>

        <div class="form-actions">
          <div><%= link_to_add_association 'adicionar ingrediente', f, :meal_ingredients, 'data-association-insertion-node' => "#ingredients ol", 'data-association-insertion-method' => "append", :wrap_object => Proc.new {|quantity| quantity.build_ingredient; quantity }, :class => "btn btn-default" %></div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <div><%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-success" %></div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This _form render the following **_meal_ingredient_fields** partial

```
<div class = "nested-fields">
  <table class= "table">
      <thead>
        *
        *
        *
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <%= f.fields_for :ingredient do |fi| %>
            <%= fi.hidden_field :id %>
          <td scope="row" class="col-md-4">
            <%= fi.autocomplete_field :name, autocomplete_ingredient_name_ingredients_path, :id_element => '#ingredient_id', class: "form-control" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= fi.text_field :unit, required: true, class: "form-control unit_input" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= fi.text_field :carb, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control carb_input" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= fi.text_field :prot, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control prot_input" %>
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= fi.text_field :fat, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control fat_input" %>
          </td>
          <% end %>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= f.number_field :quantity, required: true, :pattern => '^\d+(\.\d+)*$', title: "Apenas números separados por pontos", class: "form-control" %>

          </td>          
          <td class="col-md-1">
          </td>
          <td class="col-md-1">
            <%= link_to_remove_association "remove item", f, :class => "btn btn-danger" %>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

---

**JAVASCRIPT:**
ingredients.js

```
 $(function(){
  var num;
  var id;
  $('#ingredients').on('cocoon:after-insert', function(e, insertedItem) {
    $('input[id^="meal_meal_ingredients_attributes_"][id$="_ingredient_attributes_name"]').each(function(){
        var current = $(this);
        var rx = /meal_meal_ingredients_attributes_(.*)_ingredient_attributes_name/;
        num = rx.exec(current.attr('id'))[1];
        id = '#meal_meal_ingredients_attributes_'+ num +'_ingredient_attributes_';
    });
    $(id + 'name').bind('railsAutocomplete.select', function(event, data){
      $( id + 'id' ).val( data.item.id);
      $( id + 'unit' ).val( data.item.unit).prop('disabled', true);
      $( id + 'carb' ).val( data.item.carb).prop('disabled', true);
      $( id + 'prot' ).val( data.item.prot).prop('disabled', true);
      $( id + 'fat' ).val( data.item.fat).prop('disabled', true);
    });
  });
});
```

*In case of needing something else, this is my repo: https://github.com/betinhosaad/inutree* 
Thank you!

**EDITED**
PARAMS:

```
[1] pry(#<MealsController>)> params
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"h7NGQ35IEbQXHjLc+yLzQC8E6hzfoj7AsjNauPca8Hou6bQ49nuTKjq0g9hgg2myzLw+1P6xXbv35zWUtpLh0Q==",
 "meal"=>
  {"name"=>"Foo",
=> {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"h7NGQ35IEbQXHjLc+yLzQC8E6hzfoj7AsjNauPca8Hou6bQ49nuTKjq0g9hgg2myzLw+1P6xXbv35zWUtpLh0Q==",
 "meal"=>
  {"name"=>"Foo",
   "meal_ingredients_attributes"=>
    {"1449865135634"=>{"ingredient_attributes"=>{"id"=>"1", "name"=>"Tapioca"}, "id"=>"", "quantity"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"false"},
     "1449865141143"=>
      {"ingredient_attributes"=>{"id"=>"", "name"=>"Grape", "unit"=>"und", "carb"=>"1", "prot"=>"0", "fat"=>"0"},
       "id"=>"",
       "quantity"=>"4",
       "_destroy"=>"false"}}},
 "commit"=>"Create Meal",
 "controller"=>"meals",
 "action"=>"create"}
```

Comment: I took a look at your repo, and it seems that :id is not a whitelisted attribute for meal_ingredients_attributes in your meal_params. Try adding that and see if it solves the issue.

Comment: that didn't work. I also tried to add a hidden_field input for the meal_ingredients form. Guess what? No id is assigned when I create a meal based on an existing ingredient. However, when I create a new ingredient the meal is created succesfully.

Comment: Can you show the params hash that is being passed in from the form somehow? With pry or something? I'm curious what is happening there.

Comment: In other words, it seems that, for an existing ingredient, the meal_ingredient form tries to match the ids of these two tables and not - as it was supposed to - take the id of the existing ingredient and create a new MealIngredient with that id and the Meal id.

Comment: Done. It's in the question

Comment: Since a meal has_many :ingredients through meal_ingredients, I wonder if you need meal_ingredients attributes at all in the form. You may be able to just do fields_for :ingredients directly from the meal form without the 'middle man' of meal_ingredients, since there is technically a has_many relationship there. Then you could build the meal_ingredient from the create action with the params. Have you tried/thought of this? I'm somewhat guessing, but I would give it a try.

Comment: Actually I didn't :D by doing the way you suggest, how would I set the quantity since it belongs to the meal_ingredients table? I don't wanna record the quantity in the ingredients nor meals tables

Comment: Could you add a :quantity property to your :ingredients_attributes on the permitted params, and just pass it to the controller that way? It wouldn't have to save to the ingredient, just get passed to the controller that way. Then in the controller action, you could read that param and save it to the meal_ingredient instead. You might need to add it to the the ingredient model as a attr_accessor, but I would try it without doing so. Mind you, this may not be the best way to do this, but it's an idea that just may work.